# How to migrate manually added iOS thirdpart sdk to pod version

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

We have two years old iOS app that needs to update recently.
There is an old SDK (2.0) that manually added to project. Now this SDK have 4.0 version on cocoapods and we really like to move this SDK to pod.

What is the best way to do it? just delete the library from Build Phase and pod install?
Changing the old code to support new SDK is not problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

> just delete the library from Build Phase and pod install?

Yes this would be the easiest way to go about it.
Also make sure you remove it from your local files inside the project so that Xcode cannot get confused, make sure you remove all remains of the pod (except the code ofcourse).